# Get folders and files from SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, rest, provider-hosted-app, jsom

I am working on an Provider hosted app, scenario is to get all folders and files from SharePoint library and display on UI(more like a view). Need some tips to do it.
I mean how to create a UI similar to SharePoint "All Documents" View but using REST/JSOM in a app.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Getting the files and folders, from the library is not  a big deal you use CSOM/REST Api calls recursively and can get the complete folder structure. But list like UI is almost not possible in the provider hosted addin. You can try the latest Office Fabric UI, to match look n feel but it won't give you all the features like list view.

Comment: I don't need all the features , my requirement is to get UI look like a View with all folders along with documents.

Comment: Then have a look at the Office UI Fabric -  [Table component](http://dev.office.com/fabric/components/table)